# How can I know whether a file is being used by other process by using c++ under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I want to copy a file to another file. But it always failed. I checked my code carefully, but I still can not know what's wrong with it. So I guess may be one of the two files is being used by other process. So firstly, I want to check whether they are being used by other process.

If so, is there any solution to stop the procedure by using c++??

Comment: Why don't you show us your copying code that fails? Create a [mcve]. Linux is usually pretty lax about letting processes read, write to, rename, and delete each other's files. File contention is more of a Windows problem than a Linux one. It's not impossible, but it's rare.

Comment: Checking it from C++ would be trying to plaster over the problem. But in the meantime look up `lsof`.

Comment: Al, I did nothing and this problem seems that it has been solved. Really peculiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code *always* fails, I would assume that it's because there is a problem with the code, because that's where the problem is in approximately 99.999%<sup>1</sup> of the cases.

That said, there isn't much point in checking if you can open a file before you try, since some other process might open (or lock, or remove, ...) the file between your checking and your opening it.

The reliable method is to just go ahead and try to open the file, and then handle failure gracefully (which you need to do anyway).

---

Footnotes:

<sup>1</sup> Scientific fact that I just made up.